# Datatype mismatch converting SAS numeric to Teradata BIGINT

Tags: sas, teradata, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I have a SAS dataset with a numeric variable ACCT_ID (among other fields). Its attributes in a `PROC CONTENTS` are:

```
#    Variable                 Type    Len    Format    Informat    Label
1    ACCT_ID                  Num       8    19.       19.         ACCT_ID
```

I know that this field doesn't have any non-integer values in it, so I want to store it as a BIGINT in Teradata, and I've specified this with the `dbtype` data set option like this:

```
data td.output(dbtype=(ACCT_ID="BIGINT", <etc etc>));
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
ERROR: Datatype mismatch for column: ACCT_ID.
```

There are no missing or non-integer values in that field, and the error persists even if I round ACCT_ID using `round(acct_id, 1)` to explicitly remove any floating point values that *could* exist.

Strangely enough, no error is given if I assign this to be a DECIMAL(18,0) in Teradata rather than a BIGINT. I guess that could be one workaround, but I'd like to understand how I can create integer fields in Teradata from SAS numeric variables like this given that SAS doesn't distinguish types between integer and floating point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS does not support the BIGINT datatype. See http://support.sas.com/kb/34/729.html.

> Teradata's BIGINT data type is not supported in SAS/ACCESS Interface
> to Teradata. You cannot read or update a table containing a column
> with the BIGINT data type in SAS/ACCESS Interface to Teradata.
> Attempting to do so generates the following error message:
>
> ERROR: At least one of the columns in this DBMS table has  a datatype that is
> not supported by this engine.